# Recording a webpage stream with multiple requests using PhantomJS & ffmpeg to /dev/stdout leads to ffmpeg error

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, phantomjs

First of all, sorry for my english.

I'm in a quest for days. I've researched everywhere and I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I'm using Nodejs, Phantomjs and ffmpeg in this scenary:

- An user enters the site, login with facebook and he can ask for a video with his name and some random photos (gathered by /me/ & sent via JSON POST);
- Node receive the user data, creates a child process (PhantomJS + ffmpeg) and awaits for a response to send the video URL to the user.

When I run a single instance of this request, everything is working fine. BUT, when two or more users make the request, only one video is sent and the others process end up in a ffmpeg stream error.

I think the reason is that all the ffmpeg processes are using the same place (/dev/stdout). Since one process is already using it, the others enters in a "can't access" error. But it is a assumption, I don't know how /dev/stdout really works.

Here are my codes. (I have removed some lines and renamed some variables for better understanding, sorry for any mistake)

index.js:

```
var generateVideo = 'phantomjs phantom.js '+videoID+' '+userID+' | ffmpeg -vcodec png -f image2pipe -r 30 -i - -pix_fmt yuv420p public/videos/'+userID+'/'+videoID+'.mp4 -y';

childProcess.exec(generateVideo, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    var json    = {};
    json.video  = '/videos/'+userID+'/'+videoID+'.mp4';
    res.send(json);
});
```

phantom.js:

```
var page            = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize   = { width: 1366, height: 768 };
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 10000;

var args            = require('system').args;
var videoID         = args[1];
var userID          = args[2];

page.open('http://localhost:3000/recordvideo/'+videoID, 'post', function(status){
    var frame       = 0;
    var target_fps  = 30;
    var maxframes   = page.evaluate(function () {
                        return getTotalDurationInSeconds();
                    }) * target_fps;

    setInterval(function(){
        page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: "png" });
        if( frame >= maxframes ){
            phantom.exit();
        }
        frame++;
    }, (1000 / target_fps));
});
```

And the error:

```
[Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c phantomjs phantom.js XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX | ffmpeg -vcodec png -f image2pipe -r 30 -i - -pix_fmt yuv420p public/videos/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX.mp4 -y
www-0 ffmpeg version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
www-0   built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
www-0   configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
www-0   libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
www-0   libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
www-0   libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
www-0   libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
www-0   libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
www-0   libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
www-0   libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
www-0   libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
www-0   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
www-0 [png @ 0x3d7c4a0] Invalid PNG signature 0x46726F6D20506861.
www-0 [image2pipe @ 0x3d72780] decoding for stream 0 failed
www-0 [image2pipe @ 0x3d72780] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: png, none(pc)): unspecified size
www-0 Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
www-0 Input #0, image2pipe, from 'pipe:':
www-0   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
www-0     Stream #0:0: Video: png, none(pc), 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
www-0 [buffer @ 0x3d81540] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
www-0 [buffer @ 0x3d81540] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
www-0 [buffer @ 0x3d81540] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
www-0 [buffer @ 0x3d81540] Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.
www-0 [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x3d72600] Error applying options to the filter.
www-0 Error opening filters!
www-0 ]
```

I really hope that I can find an answer here!
And sorry if there already is an answer for this. But I researched for days.

Thank you in advance!